# Should we advertise on MobileRead forums?

Tags: discussion, advertising

As far as I know, the [MobileRead](http://mobileread.com/) community is one of the largest and knowledgeable about ebooks and digital reading.

Despite not even being registered, I've been lurking their forums since a lot of time and its really a gold mine of useful informations.

Do you think that we should make that community aware of this site existence?

Comment: As an aside, we can cross-promote on SE sites (SFF at least), both in chat and possibly on meta. Not sure how banner promotions work.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say the proper thing to do is to check with a moderator on that forum first. This site is sort of competition to that site and they may not appreciate us advertising on their forum (it may be considered spam).

Answer (score 6):

> Despite not even being registered...

If you'd already established yourself as a user on the forum, I'd have said, "Why not?"  But since you are not already a known-quantity over there, I advise caution.  As a default, the [standards we have on this site](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) seem good:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

Now, other sites have other rules.  Some are geared toward all sorts of promotion—especially self-promotion.  Others are even more protective than we are.  In any case, it doesn't help promote the site if "spreading the word" looks like spamming.  Follow what ever guidelines the site you are posting on provide.

MobileRead's [guidelines](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/faq.php?faq=vb_faq#faq_posting_guidelines) read:

> **5. Advertising and Promotion**
>
> Please post in our [Flea Market](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=124) section if you want to buy or sell a reading device (or other item relevant to mobile reading) for your personal use only.
>
> If you have something to promote – e.g. a new book, a new reading device, or other item relevant to mobile reading, then you may announce it, and respond to questions, in the [Self-Promotions forum](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=226). Please read and follow the additional [Promotion Posting Guidelines](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=90052). Members who abuse these guidelines may be treated as spammers.

I don't know how promoting Ebooks.SE would be labeled.  It would probably be best to ask first.